# How to use a reactive variable in server Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, output, radar-chart

I would like to create an application such as below, only at the beginning is to choose the number of cylinders. The following example selects a database, I would like to give up and go straight to the selection of cylinders. Can I use the filter option here?

**My idea:**

```
 df_mtcars <- reactive({
    cylinder_selected <- as.numeric(input$si_cylinders[1])        
    df <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == cylinder_selected)        
    return(df)
  })
```

**My code:**

***ui:***

```
library(radarchart)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(      
  headerPanel("Car Comparison Radar"),      
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    uiOutput("choose_car"),
    uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),          
  mainPanel(
    chartJSRadarOutput('radar', height = '350px')    
  )
))
```

***server:***

```
library(shiny)
library(radarchart)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # choose dataset but I want choose cyl
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    data_sets <- "mtcars"
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", data_sets)
  })

  # select a car
  output$choose_car <- renderUI({
    selectInput("car","car",as.list(rownames(get(input$dataset))))
  })

  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    dat <- get(input$dataset)
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })            
  output$radar <- renderChartJSRadar({

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    #reform data for plot
    dat <- as.data.frame(t(dat), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dat$labs <- row.names(dat)
    dat <- dat[, c('labs', input$car)]
    chartJSRadar(dat)
  })
 })
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you are looking for, sorry. Can't you just repeat what you've done but have a `uiOutput("choose_cylinder")` option? And then when you read `dat <- get(input$dataset)`, filter it to the cylinder they set? p.s. you need `library(radarchart)` in the `ui.r` script too in order to deploy the app ;)

Comment: I would like to add a checkbox with a number of cylinders at the beginning instead of selecting a data set. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is `uiOutput("choose_car")` gives you all car possibilities. If you add a `selectInput`for selection of cylinders you will have a problem, because you have some specific cars for each cylinder numbers.

So you could have your `selectInput`for cars conditional on `selectInput`for cylinders.

You can remove `uiOutput("choose_dataset")` on your own so based on your example you could try this:

```
ui = pageWithSidebar(      
  headerPanel("Car Comparison Radar"),      
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    uiOutput("choose_cyclinder"),
    uiOutput("choose_car"),
    uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),          
  mainPanel(
    chartJSRadarOutput('radar', height = '350px')    
  )
)



server = function(input, output) {


  output$choose_cyclinder <- renderUI({

    temp <-  mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(Counts = n()) 
    cyl <- levels(as.factor(temp$cyl))
    selectInput("select_cyl", "Choose a cylinder", as.list(cyl), selected=TRUE, multiple = FALSE)
  })



  # choose dataset but I want choose cyl
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    data_sets <- "mtcars"
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", data_sets)
  })

  # select a car
  output$choose_car <- renderUI({

    dat <- get(input$dataset)
    dat <- dat %>% tibble::rownames_to_column('carnames') %>%
    filter(cyl %in% c(input$select_cyl)) %>%
      tibble::column_to_rownames('carnames')
    selectInput("car","car",as.list(rownames(dat)))
  })



  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    dat <- get(input$dataset)
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })            
  output$radar <- renderChartJSRadar({

    # Get the data set
    dat <- get(input$dataset)
   # dat <- mtcars

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

   # dat <- dat %>% filter(cyl %in% c(input$select_cyl))

    #reform data for plot
    dat <- as.data.frame(t(dat), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dat$labs <- row.names(dat)
    dat <- dat[, c('labs', input$car)]
    chartJSRadar(dat)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT:

```
ui = pageWithSidebar(      
  headerPanel("Car Comparison Radar"),      
  sidebarPanel(
    #uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
    uiOutput("choose_cyclinder"),
    uiOutput("choose_car"),
    uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),          
  mainPanel(
    chartJSRadarOutput('radar', height = '350px')    
  )
)



server = function(input, output) {


  output$choose_cyclinder <- renderUI({

    temp <-  mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(Counts = n()) 
    cyl <- levels(as.factor(temp$cyl))
    selectInput("select_cyl", "Choose a cylinder", as.list(cyl), selected=TRUE, multiple = FALSE)
  })



  # choose dataset but I want choose cyl
#  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
#    data_sets <- "mtcars"
#    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", data_sets)
#  })

  # select a car
  output$choose_car <- renderUI({

   # dat <- get(mtcars)
    dat <- mtcars
    dat <- dat %>% tibble::rownames_to_column('carnames') %>%
      filter(cyl %in% c(input$select_cyl)) %>%
      tibble::column_to_rownames('carnames')
    selectInput("car","car",as.list(rownames(dat)))
  })



  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
  #  if(is.null(input$dataset))
   #   return()

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
   # dat <- get(input$dataset)
    dat <- mtcars
    colnames <- names(dat)

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  })            
  output$radar <- renderChartJSRadar({

    # Get the data set
    #dat <- get(input$dataset)
     dat <- mtcars

    # Make sure columns are correct for data set (when data set changes, the
    # columns will initially be for the previous data set)
    if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
      return()

    # Keep the selected columns
    dat <- dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]

    # dat <- dat %>% filter(cyl %in% c(input$select_cyl))

    #reform data for plot
    dat <- as.data.frame(t(dat), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dat$labs <- row.names(dat)
    dat <- dat[, c('labs', input$car)]
    chartJSRadar(dat)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am coming back to your solution and I care about removing `uiOutput ("choose_dataset")`

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? When I run my solution, when I unclick some of the columns it creates a new graph each time. If you unclick all columns except two, you will see only a straight line between the two selected columns.

Comment: I get an error Error in select (., Colnames (data)): unused argument (colnames (data))

Comment: @Elia, Just play with the cyclinder. You have different combinations of cylinder and car. If you want to change that you should use `updateSelectInput` so the `car selectinput` changes according to the `cylinder selectInput`.